# Giving Linux user git access but not shell access?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I want to give commit access to several different people, each to their own separate git repository on my Linux server.

One way to do this would be:

```
foreach user x
    adduser x
    create /home/x/repo.git
    ask user x to clone from ssh://myserver.com/home/x/repo.git
```

However this has the undesirable effect that they could also login via ssh.  I do not want to give them shell access.

Is there anyway to set it up in a similar way, but purely give them git commit access and not shell access?

Comment: Hi guys, how about we move this question to another stackexchange site and allow it to open to have more answers?

Answer (score 17):

Set [`/usr/bin/git-shell`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) as their shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Or use native `git` protocol instead of `ssh`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the users' login shell to [git-shell](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) (comes with git), which is "restricted login shell for Git-only SSH access". It will let the users use `git push` and `git pull` as normal, but won't let them log in. Instructions for setting it up can be found from the bottom of this page: http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (Gitkeeper) to manage the access of your git repositories.

Otherwise you have to set up a chroot.