# git file permissions over ssh/git-shell?

Tags: git, ssh

I've setup a private bare git repository `foo.git` for a developer on my server, and gave them access over ssh via the login shell `git-shell`.

As it is a multi-user system the bare repository I setup for them had `chmod -R o-rwx foo.git` run on it, so other users on the same system could not access this repository.

The trouble is when the developer pushes changes the new files created in the git repository (for example new objects or new branch tags) are world readable.

How do I tell git, ssh, git-shell or whatever - that when it creates files in foo.git they should be chmod `o-rwx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `git config --help` and search for `core.sharedRepository`.

If I understood it correctly for your configuration you have to put this in the `config`-file:

```
[core]
    sharedRepository = 0666
```

.

Comment: This is the thing I was looking for (but actually I want `sharedRepository = 0640`).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use (something like) Gitolite to manage the access to the repositories?

It gives you very good control over the access to the repositories (even about the branches separately, if you want), and uses only a single Unix user account (Usually called 'git') for all your git users. (This is similar to how github.com works.).

Comment: Yeah, we [took a look at Gitolite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065751/giving-linux-user-git-access-but-not-shell-access), however it seemed overkill for our needs, plus we want to have everyone with their own unix account because we may want to add other services.